# Check if cross-origin iframe is about to intersect with parent page using IntersectionObserver

Tags: javascript, iframe, intersection-observer

I have a **cross-origin** `iframe` embedded in a parent page.

[image: cross-origin iframe]

I want to know when my `<iframe>` shows up in visible viewport. I can use `IntersectionObserver` for that:

```js
// inside cross-origin iframe
let observer = new IntersectionObserver(cb, {
    root: null
})
observer.observe(document.documentElement)
```

When I use `root: null` (default value), I'm in *implicit root* mode, so `root` defaults to *top-level document* (exactly what I want), and when observing `document.documentElement` of the iframe, the observer calculates the intersection with the parent page.

As I scroll the parent page and `<iframe>` *intersects* with the parent page, I correctly get a callback from the `IntersectionObserver`.

**However, is it possible to know whether the `<iframe>` is *about to intersect*? (for example, it's out of visible viewport, but very close?)**

Comment: Interesting: there is an interop issue here. https://jsfiddle.net/ne9sytcr/1 In Firefox this fiddle works as intended (it detects the elements before their frame enters the screen). In Chrome and Safari it will only fire when the iframe enters the viewport. I don't know who's right though...

Comment: Ha, interesting idea to observe an element with negative fixed position instead of body. Too bad it's not cross-browser :)

Comment: I don't think it's possible unless the iframe is same-origin.

Comment: So that was probably a bug in Firefox. It seems they fixed it the latest nightly.

Comment: This would be really a security violation if the intersection observer can check something when embedded into an iframe on the cross-origin (I can imagine use case with clickjacking where this could be exploited). Cross-Origin iframes are kind of sandboxed (even without sandbox attributes restrictions) by Cross-Origin Policy and you can only interact with parent using post messages. If I'm mistaken please show me an example where iframe can detect anything that belongs to parent window. That would be really a security issue.

Answer (score 0):

*TL;DR  It does not seem to be possible in general case for the cross-origin frame.*

Non-solutions:

- `rootMargin`: There's a `rootMargin` property of `IntersectionObserver` whose purpose is exactly that; however according to the spec, [it is ignored when dealing with cross-origin iframes](https://w3c.github.io/IntersectionObserver/#dom-intersectionobserver-rootmargin).
- `root: document` is not a solution, because then the intersections are calculated *within the iframe* (and `document.documentElement` *always* intersects with `document`)
- changing observed `target` to `iframe` is not possible, because trying to get `iframe` DOM handle *from within the iframe* will result in cross-origin security violation exception.

Comment: How about nest the iframe inside some other element?

Comment: @hackape My iframe is cross-origin and I don't have control over the embedders. But anyway, I don't think I can observe arbitrary parent DOM node when cross-origin (I can't get DOM node ref to elements from parent page when cross-origin), and AFAIU, I can only implicitly observe top-level document's root.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think it's possible unless the iframe is same-origin.